# PTIJ: Destroying Avodah Zara - Pandora's box

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Is one Halachically allowed to smash and destroy Pandora's Box which is considered Avodah Zara, or is this considered a Sakana because it will unleash untold horrors to the world?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 2):

First, [it wasn't a box](https://mythus.fandom.com/wiki/Pandora%27s_Pithos), it was a *[pithos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pithos)* (πίθος), which is a kind of jar. Second, the [mishna](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Rosh_Hashanah.3.7?vhe=Torat_Emet_357&lang=bi) actually deals with this question:

> "התוקע לתוך הבור או לתוך הדות או לתוך הפטס, אם קול שופר שמע, יצא"
> "If one sounds a shofar into a pit, or into a cistern, or into a pithos, if he clearly heard the sound of the shofar, it can come out."

The mishna tells us that if one comes upon this pithos, he should blow a shofar into it. If he hears a shofar sound coming back, that means that whatever's inside can come out. The reason being that only Jewish demons would answer a shofar call with another shofar call, and it's okay to allow Jewish demons to roam free, as they are meant to fulfill Hashem's commands. So if one were to come upon Pandora's pithos, one should do the shofar-check. If one hears the shofar, it would be okay to open the pithos, or even destroy it - anything to free the Jewish demons inside.

But what if you don't hear a shofar answering you, i.e., that the evil entities inside aren't Jewish?

There are two options:

1. The first option is to only slightly damage the pithos on one of its ear-like handles, which according to the [mishna in Avodah Zara 4:5](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Avodah_Zarah.4.5?vhe=Torat_Emet_357&lang=bi) is enough of an iconoclastic act to deface the idolatrous object.
2. If for some reason there is need to destroy the whole Pandorian pithos, or else the evil entities have already begun escaping, you still have your trusty shofar with you, which is an excellent, tried-and-tested tool for banishing unwanted sorts ([Sanhedrin 107b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sanhedrin.107b.13?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi), [Moed Katan 16a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Moed_Katan.16a.8?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi)). Just blow loudly and that should be enough to banish them from this world.

So, to conclude: If need be to destroy Pandora's pithos, you may do so, but only if you have a shofar around.